# Can't run program in Netbeans 7.3

Tags: compiling, libraries, c++, netbeans

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 and installed Netbeans 7.3 on it (not the Ubuntu version, directly from the website). I'm trying to run a basic C++ program that uses Allegro 5 but, even though it compiles, it cannot run. When the project is located on a different partition the error it gives is:

`/bin/sh: 1: exec: pathToProject/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/projectName: Permission denied`

However, when I copy the project directly to my home folder it gives me the following error:

`X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  13
  Current serial number in output stream:  13`

Here is the program if it helps:

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main()
{
    al_init();
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = al_create_display (1000,1000);
    al_clear_to_color (al_map_rgb (255,255,255));
    al_flip_display ();
    al_rest(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the `glx-libraries` in Ubuntu installed?

What about the `mesa-glx-libraries`?

Comment: No. Do I just type `sudo apt-get install glx-libraries` to install them?

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.

Answer (score 0):

no not too quick ! in your code-snippet is return missing ? or is it only one block of many different blocks ?

I was wrong - it is not matter of glx-libraries - but this is slightly off-topic here and dealing with programming in c++ resp. with g++ of gnu - what compiler you are using in netbeans ?

allegro as header-file is part in g++ of gnu, but g++ is part of netbeans.

for example gnu-compiler g++ can deal with allegro-header-file but you need to link it
in it terminal.

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/68527/g-allegro-linking

as I read here allegro is at present "sticky" with g++ in netbeans - here is complete forum about ...

https://netbeans.org/    (type here as search word "allegro" in right corner)

Comment: I am using g++ but, as far I'm aware, I already linked allegro. Under project->properties->Linker->libraries->add options->other options and there I wrote `-lallegro -lallegro_image` etc.

Comment: And it was missing a return, but it does not change anything.